# Right aligned background image does not follow body min-width

Tags: html, css

I created a layout with a right handed column, and I have added a faux column background to fill the entire browser viewport height-wise. The body tag has a min-width of 1024px defined, but although resizing the browser to less than that will prevent the overall layout from shrinking down further, the background continues to follow the viewport of the browser. How can I prevent this from happening?

incorrect:

[image: incorrect]

correct:

[image: correct]

css:

```
    body {
    color:#1a1a1a;
    background:#fafafa;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-width: 1024px;
    }
    div#page-container {
    min-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto -42px;
    }
    .sidebar-right {
    background: url(/bundles/backomaticcp/img/sidebar-bg-r.gif) repeat-y right; 
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This usually happens with faux-columns. What you can do is to instead of using a background image, insert the `<img>` and `position: absolute` relative to container.

Comment: Is there a way to have a "repeat-y" for images?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, I have a div with an id of "page" and is within div#page-container, and it inherited the background. All I had to do was set the background to none in div#page, and all is well.